# PHP cant connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$link) 
{
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I get this error:

Could not connect: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Why?

Edit:

```
$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="test";

    function Save($name)
    {
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
        $query = "INSERT INTO test (name)" .
                 "VALUES ('" . $name . "')";
        mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();
    }
```

Comment: You have two correct answers below. Make sure you use `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `display_errors` set to `On` (or at least logged to a file) on your development server. It will help for this kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit, the issue appears to be a scoping one.

You're attempting to make a connection inside a function where the `$username`, `$password` and `$database` variables are defined outside that function.

I suggest you read the [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the manual and turn up your error reporting as @netcoder suggests in the question comments.

Answer (score 5):

Did you give `$username` and `$password` values? Something like this?

```
$username="root";
$password="";
```

Comment: @slandau: Could you show us the code? Or are "www-data" the username and "" the password?

Answer (score 2):

Your `$password` variable is empty (`(using password: NO)`) then you trying log into `www-data` user without password, and server result is access denied. Propably this user have setted password.

Comment: `www-data` is what Apache in some distros runs under, so the `$username` seems to be empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, you are trying to connect to the database twice.
Somewhere in your code, you are already trying to connect to the database with username as "www-data"...... and again you are connecting to the database with username "root".

Also the password you are providing with the username "www-data" is wrong, thats y you getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="test";

    function Save($name)
    {
        global $username;
        global $password;
        global $database;

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
        $query = "INSERT INTO test (name)" .
                 "VALUES ('" . $name . "')";
        mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();
    }
```