# mysqli_connect not selecting database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP cant connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082938/php-cant-connect-to-mysql)

MySQLI is not correctly selecting my database. I am sure that the database exists and is properly named. Running this page in MAMP outputs "Database connection failed: No database selected". My version of MAMP does support MySQLI. Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks!

```
<?php 
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'my_db';

query();

function query(){
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO names (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')");

   if(!$query){
    echo "Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
   }

   mysqli_close();
   }


?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php The second example is explicit.

Comment: Thanks Phil! That was it! Stupid mistake sorry that I wasted your time.